# C# WinForms get value from quote text

Tags: c#, regex

How i can get `George Bush` from:

```
"<LABEL>დასახელება ან სახელი, გვარი</LABEL> <INPUT id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBuyerName class=inactive_input title=\"მაქსიმალური სიმბოლოების რაოდენობა 90\" name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtBuyerName readOnly value=\"George Bush\"> "
```

I tried almost all patterns which returned google.

Please help me i am trying already 3 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser. For example, http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: You need only regex solution? ` string input = ...;
 string pattern = "value=\"";
 int start = input.LastIndexOf(pattern);
 int end = input.IndexOf("\"", start + pattern.Length);
 start += pattern.Length;
 string output1 = input.Substring(start, end - start);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
string input = ...;
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"value=""([^""]*)""");
if (match.Success) {
  var name = match.Groups[1].Value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Visual studio givs exception on this >> @"value=""([^"]*)"""